# Are there other re-orchestrations of Schumann's symphonies besides Mahler's?

Tags: orchestration

Like for example, maybe Stokowski?

Bonus question: have Mahler's re-orchestrations ever been recorded and packaged without giving Mahler credit?

Comment: Plenty, but they tend to be rather minor and not really noticeable for most listeners.

Comment: I don't think ELP ever covered Mahler, but they were infamous for recording a wide range of classical pieces without attribution. Not exactly what you were asking, but a number of pop/rock singers did odd things to classical melodies.

Answer (score 3):

I remember a time when it was remarkable for a conductor to record a Schumann symphony with the original orchestration, as Leonard Bernstein did in 1960, with "ORIGINAL ORCHESTRATION" right on the cover -- whether as a selling point or a warning, I don't know.

This page http://www.classicalnotes.net/classics3/schumannsym.html will tell you quite a bit about 20th-century conductors and what they each did.  Almost always, the particular conductor made his own changes, usually without any indication in the liner notes.